# read data from excel and store in db using spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entity

read data from excel and store in db using spring boot jpa.

i have an excel that looks like this.

```
address         Name
---------------------
XYZ             ABC
ZX              BC
```

**My service Class:**

```
 public class SpreadSheetService{
    @Autowired
    SpreadSheetRepo spreadSheetRepo;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper=new ModelMapper() ;
    public void readExcelSheet() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/spreadsheet.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet getSheet=workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    List<SEntity> dataList= modelMapper.map(result(getSheet), new TypeToken<List<SEntity>>(){}.getType());
    spreadSheetRepo.saveAll(dataList);
    }

    List<SEntity> result(XSSFSheet getSheet){
    Iterator<Row> rowItr = getSheet.iterator();
    boolean flag=false;
    List<SEntity> list=new ArrayList<>();
    while(rowItr.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowItr.next();
    SEntity obj=new  SEntity();
    Iterator<Cell> cellItr = row.cellIterator();
    if(flag==true) {
    while(cellItr.hasNext()) {
    Cell cell = cellItr.next();
    int index = cell.getColumnIndex();
    switch(index) {
    case 0:
    obj.setAddress(cell.toString());
    break;
    case 1:
    obj.setName(cell.toString());
    break;
         }
       }
        list.add(obj);  
      }
       flag=true;
     }
    return list;
    }
    }
```

**My Entity Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="spreadsheet")
@Data
public class SEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
int id;

@Column(name="name")
String name;

@Column(name="address")
String address;

}
```

**My Repo Class:**

```
@Repository
public interface SpreadSheetRepo extends CrudRepository<SEntity,Integer> {

}
```

Above code is working fine as expected. but what if i have 30 or more columns? defining index 0 to 30 or based on number of columns in switch case does not look good to me.

is there any other way to achieve the scenario?

Comment: You can write dynamic code if your excel header and entity property are the same.

Comment: i haven't used this but it looks promising in your scenario, have a look at https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji

Comment: JPA may not be the best tool for the job in this case. Hibernate does offer a dynamic model using maps https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/dynamic_model.html however maybe raw JDBC is a better fit in this case?